# WordPress Multisite with root as a sub domain

Tags: cpanel, wordpress

I am looking at creating a few websites within WordPress however I am having difficulty setting up multi-site. I have a few projects installed on my server along side my instillation of WordPress and they are all under the same domain. They are broken under separate sub-domains for grouped projects.

When activating multi-site within WordPress it generated a loop error when trying to visit the site. I am hoping to make it so WordPress is under the sub-domain of 'host' and all websites I create under this end in their own file extension (unless a separate domain is provided directly to the site within WordPress).

Each individual project is hosted within its own directory on the server and wordpress is located under '/host' within the root directory.

```
root directory
    project 1 - sub1.domain.com
    project 2 - sub2.domain.com
    WordPress - host.domain.com
        Site 1 - host.domain.com/site1
        Site 2 - host.domain.com/site2
```

I have created a wildcard within cPanel it's self pointing towards the directory as indicated by a few guides which doesn't seem to have any effect and I have also tried a few settings within the WordPress config file. The Loop error has been replaced with a 404 page.

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'domain.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

When I attempt to visit host.domain.com it redirects to

```
domain.com/wp-signup.php?new=host
```

displaying a 404 page however I can access the site by visiting www.domian.com/host

I can see the 'My Sites' option within the admin area to create the separate sites however when I do click on 'Sites' within the menu it generates a 404 error as it redirects to

```
domain.com/wp-admin/network/sites.php
```

ignoring the /host directory. How can I go about putting WordPress under it's own sub-domain of host.domain.com and run off of this extension ignoring www.domain.com/host completely and create any WordPress websites under this format (host.domain.com/###)?